yathesis leadchapter error: ! Undefined control sequence. l.1 \leadchapter
I am using yathesis to write my PhD thesis.
I get only one error when compiling on my second computer, and it is this:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \leadchapter

It only goes away when I remove the \leadchapter command. However, I do not understand why the error exists in the first place ?
(It compiles perfectly well on my laptop.)
And how can I get rid of it?

probably the tex system on your computer is too old.
